# External json parser before the hearing is visible

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to get an external json before the view is visible and active, but $ http.get not work until the view is visible. I'm dealing with $ ionicView.beforeEnter

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
                var value = window.localStorage.getItem("url_id");
                var values = value.split("//");
                $scope.url_id = values[1];    
                $http.get(CategoriaDatos.local + $scope.url_id).then(function (resp) {
                    $scope.local = resp.data;
                 }, function (err) {
                    console.error('ERR', err);
                })
     });
```

Once the view is active and visible the get method works and gets the data.

Comment: Try wrapping the $http in a service or factory and call that method from $scope.$on

Comment: I wrapped myself in a service, but it's the same, once the view is active and visible the function is executed

Comment: why not get the data when the app loads and store it in a service and then just pass it to state when it is loaded?

Comment: @Jess This solved my problem could propose in response to qualify